# Decay of a function from its Laplace transform

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform

Let $f:[0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function whose Laplace transform $$ F(s) = \int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st} dt $$ is convergent for all $Re(s) >0$.
Assume further that $F(s)$ can be extended analytically to the closed half plane $\{ Re(s)\ge 0 \}$ (i.e., no singularities on the imaginary axis).
How can we prove that $f(t) \to 0$ as $t\to \infty$?

Attempt: If $F(s)$ is a rational function, this follows from the [Final Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_value_theorem#Standard_Final_Value_Theorem). But I couldn't find a proof of the Theorem.

I am thinking of using the inverse Laplace transform $$ f(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}F(s)e^{st}ds $$ for $c>0$, then push $c\to 0$, and then apply Riemann-Lebesgue lemma. But I am stuck on proving the function $y\to F(iy)$ belongs to $L^1$ or $L^2$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any $f \in L^1[0,\infty)$ will satisfy the first condition but it does not follow that $f(t) \to 0$, so you need more conditions to derive the above conclusion.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks for pointing this out. Let's assume $f$ continuous

Comment: Continuity is not sufficient.

Comment: @copper.hat I see. The question is meant to prove a result similar to the linked Final Value Theorem without assuming $F$ is rational. I don't really want to assume $f(\infty)$ exists. Do you have a suggestion to what assumptions should be made?

Comment: All proofs I have seen require  the transform of $f'$ to be convergent and the limit of $f$ to exist

Comment: There are some "nice" functions that don't have $f(t) \to 0$. For instance, consider a function $f(x)$ that is typically $0$, but around integer values $n^2$ behaves like a rectangle of height $1$ and width $1/n^2$. Such an $f$ can be chosen to be continuous, but is in $L^1$. Assuming something like finite Sobolev norms would probably suffice.

Comment: If $f$ is bounded and locally integrable, then your assumption on $F$ implies that $\int_0^\infty f(t)dt$ exists and equals $F(0)$ (Wiener–Ikehara theorem). But the existence of the integral of $f$ does not imply $f\to 0$. Haar's Tauberian theorem may be helpful.